# How to check if an CABasicAnimation is applied and running already?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation

I create a CABasicAnimation and apply it to a layer like this:

```
[rotatedLayer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"transform.rotation.z"];
```

How can I check if the rotatedLayer is already animating on the transform.rotation.z path?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the return value of `[rotatedLayer animationForKey:@"transform.rotation.z"];`.

Comment: Its swift conversion is - rotatedLayer.animation(forKey: "transform.rotation.z")

Answer (score 5):

You can set an ivar such as:

```
BOOL _animationRunning;
```

and set the delegate for your animation to be the class you're in and implement the functions:

```
animationDidStart:(CAAnimation *)anim
animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag
```

and flip the boolean within those callbacks.
Ole's method works as well but if you set the beginTime to have a delay or wrap the animation in an CAAnimationGroup to create a delay (a la [CAKeyframeAnimation delay before repeating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191755/cakeyframeanimation-delay-before-repeating)) then you have getting the animationForKey would also return that animation even though it isn't actually "animating".

Comment: I used a counter that increased in animationDidStart and decreased in animationDidStop. if it's zero - no more animations running =]