# UIButton Heartbeat Animation

Tags: swift, animation

I've created a heart beat animation for a UIButton. However, there is no way to stop this animation as it's an endless code loop. After tinkering with numerous UIView animation code blocks I've been unable to get `UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat` to produce what I need. If I could do that I could simply `button.layer.removeAllAnimations()` to remove the animations. What is a way to write this that allows for removal of the animation? I'm thinking a timer possibly but that could be kind of messy with multiple animations going on.

```
func heartBeatAnimation(button: UIButton) {

    button.userInteractionEnabled = true
    button.enabled = true

    func animation1() {

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: { () -> Void in

            button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0, 2.0)
            button.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity

        }, completion: nil)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.5, options: [], animations: { () -> Void in

            button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0, 2.0)
            button.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity

            }) { (Bool) -> Void in

                delay(2.0, closure: { () -> () in

                    animation2()

                })       
        }
    }

    func animation2() {

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: { () -> Void in

            button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0, 2.0)
            button.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity

            }, completion: nil)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.5, options: [], animations: { () -> Void in

            button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0, 2.0)
            button.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity

            }) { (Bool) -> Void in

                delay(2.0, closure: { () -> () in

                    animation1()

                })
        }
    }

    animation1()

}
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This works perfectly. The damping and spring need to be tweaked a little bit but this solves the problem. `removeAllAnimations()` clears the animation and returns the button to it's normal state.

```
button.userInteractionEnabled = true
button.enabled = true

let pulse1 = CASpringAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
pulse1.duration = 0.6
pulse1.fromValue = 1.0
pulse1.toValue = 1.12
pulse1.autoreverses = true
pulse1.repeatCount = 1
pulse1.initialVelocity = 0.5
pulse1.damping = 0.8

let animationGroup = CAAnimationGroup()
animationGroup.duration = 2.7
animationGroup.repeatCount = 1000
animationGroup.animations = [pulse1]

button.layer.addAnimation(animationGroup, forKey: "pulse")
```

This post was very helpful: [CAKeyframeAnimation delay before repeating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191755/cakeyframeanimation-delay-before-repeating)

Answer (score 12):

Swift 5 code, works without the pause between pulses:

```
    let pulse = CASpringAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
    pulse.duration = 0.4
    pulse.fromValue = 1.0
    pulse.toValue = 1.12
    pulse.autoreverses = true
    pulse.repeatCount = .infinity
    pulse.initialVelocity = 0.5
    pulse.damping = 0.8
    switchButton.layer.add(pulse, forKey: nil)
```

Answer (score 6):

I created something like this:

```
    let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")

    animation.values = [1.0, 1.2, 1.0]
    animation.keyTimes = [0, 0.5, 1]
    animation.duration = 1.0
    animation.repeatCount = Float.infinity
    layer.add(animation, forKey: "pulse")
```

Answer (score 0):

On your original question you mentioned that you want the animation to stop on command. I assume you would like it to start on command too. This solution will do both and it is quite simple.

```
func cutAnim(){
    for view in animating {
        ///I use a UIView because I wanted the container of my button to be animated. UIButton will work just fine too.
        (view.value as? UIView)?.layer.removeAllAnimations()
    }
}

func pulse(button: UIButton, name: String){
    ///Here I capture that container
    let container = button.superview?.superview
    ///Add to Dictionary
    animating[name] = container
    cutAnim()
     UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0.0, options:[UIViewAnimationOptions.repeat, UIViewAnimationOptions.autoreverse, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {
        container?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.15, y: 1.15)
        ///if you stop the animation half way it completes anyways so I want the container to go back to its original size
        container?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    }, completion: nil) 
}
```

Call cutAnim() anywhere to stop an animation, inside a timer if you want.

To start the animation use a regular button action

```
  @IBAction func buttonWasTappedAction(_ sender: Any) { 
     pulse(button: sender as! UIButton, name: "nameForDictionary")
  }
```

Hope this helps.